# How to create custom Ajax Tabs using jquery in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0.7

I have to do this in custom module. How can we achieve this in phtml file.?
You can click [here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax) for detail part. I need this kind of function in my custom module.

Comment: Can you explain more details?

Comment: @Pinku Welcome to Magento SE. We do not need details from the official jQuery UI documentation, we need info from you. What did you do so far? What did you try? On which page and which part of the page do you need this? Can you paste some code (PHP, layout XML, PHTML) that you have written so far?

Comment: @ochem Sorry but really i do not have much information about this. Just i need to do this that is my work. Can you please guide me.